# How to hide fields in backpack

Tags: laravel-backpack

Is there a proper way of hiding fields in backpack? Using the `hidden` attr or `display:none`  doesn't hide the label.

There are a couple solutions: modify every field view or hide it with js. Both have disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

There is no proper way to do it in backpack.
Once I needed to show and hide some fields according to a drop-down selection, here is the function I created:

```
const fieldVisibility = (field, visibility = true) =>
    document.querySelector(`[name*="${field}"]`).closest('.form-group').style.display =
        visibility ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Examples:

```
fieldVisibility('name', true) // Shows the field name
fieldVisibility('users', false) // Hides the field users[]
```